# Programmatic access to Google API Console's functionality

Tags: google-api, google-api-console

I would like to configure the Google API services programmatically instead of having to go through the API Console.  For example, I would like to be able to the following types of things programmatically:

- Create OAuth and API Key credentials; this would include generating
  the client id\secret, setting the redirect uri, downloading the
  client_secrets.json file, etc.
- Get the list of projects for a user
- Enable\disable services for a specified project

Does Google provide any APIs for configuring services so that I don't have to use the API Console's GUI?  All of the documentation I have seen has indicated that the only way to do this is through the API Console’s GUI.

Comment: I would love to have this functionality as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Cloud Resource Manager API](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/#v1beta1.projects) to get the list of projects for a user. Unfortunately, public APIs don't exist for the other things at this time.